# Color Mixing/Overlapping Mechanism

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Ideally I would imagine that if I overlap the `red`, `yellow`, `blue` three glasses, then I would see more or less a black color in the overlapped region.

However by doing this in LaTeX, it seems I was wrong, the overlapped region is colored by last color I use, regardless the opacity I use. Please see the following MWE and you will get what I mean.

My question is hence, what is the mechanism behind latex rendering overlapped colors? Why there is no mixing effect by using overlap?

## MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex 
\documentclass[class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle, fill=blue, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0.2cm,0cm) () {};
\node [circle, fill=red, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0cm,0cm)  () {};
\node [circle, fill=yellow, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0.1cm,0.2cm)  () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a `blend mode`

```
\documentclass[class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[transparency group]
\begin{scope}[blend mode=multiply]
\node [circle, fill=blue, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0.2cm,0cm) () {};
\node [circle, fill=red, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0cm,0cm)  () {};
\node [circle, fill=green, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0.1cm,0.2cm)  () {};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more modes see `pgfmanual` documentation, page 341, section 23.3.

For `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\begin{scope}[transparency group]
\begin{scope}[blend mode=darken]
\node [circle, fill=blue, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0.2cm,0cm) () {};
\node [circle, fill=red, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0cm,0cm)  () {};
\node [circle, fill=green, opacity=0.5, minimum size=.4cm] at (0.1cm,0.2cm)  () {};
\end{scope}
%\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have used `green` instead of `yellow` just for demo.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Sorry I did mean to type green, but I ended with typing yellow. :)

Comment: OOPS, it's not working with xelatex.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, there you go. See the edit.  Remove `transparency group`

Comment: Using latex+dvips+ps2pdf does not work either, use pdflatex it works.

Comment: @Daniel The second code works in xelatex for me.